# switching from bower_components to node_modules crashes Polymer project

Tags: polymer, yarnpkg

I have a working Polymer project when I have all my links pointing to the bower_components folder, however, when I change to node_modules I get the following message when I run

```
polymer serve
```

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

with the URL being:
http://127.0.0.1:8081/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer.html

This is correct since the Polymer team changed polymer.html to polymer.js

However, where is this done and how can I use polymer using yarn (which saves in node_modules)?

Edit:

I think I found the culprit. When I tried to find iron-icon**s** (mind the 's'), I could only find it on yarn which saves to node_modules. When I load the node module iron-icons I get the above-mentioned error message.

So I point to the bower_component iron-icon (mind you, no 's') but that doesn't provide the extensive library of icons I have with the yarn package:

on Yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/@polymer/iron-icons

but no such thing with Bower: https://bower.io/search/

Why?!

Comment: Which polymer do you use and how? They have added npm support in polymer@next (3).

Comment: I'm using the newest 3.0 which I presume the main reason. I'm guessing one of the packages still contains a reference to the .html one because when I generate a clean polymer project using yarn, all loads correctly.

Comment: Polymer form 2.x to 3.x has changed the imports from HTML imports to ES6 imports. And they've started using npm replacing bower. That should be causing most of the issues you have. 

Just to clarify, what is the exact issue you are having now? The missing icons? Would you be able to provide a small sample of the issue?